# Color 2D Grid with values from separate 2D array

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have two arrays of data, x and y. I would like to plot on a scatter plot y vs. x. The range of x is [0,3] and the range of y is [-3, 3]. I then want to grid up this region into an n by m grid and color the points in each region based on the values of a separate 2D numpy array (same shape as the grid, n by m). So, the top-leftmost grid cell of my plot should be colored based on the value of colorarr[0][0] and so on. Anyone have any suggestions on how to do this? The closest I"ve found so far is the following:

[2D grid data visualization in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229971/2d-grid-data-visualization-in-python)

Unfortunately this simply displays the colorarr, and not the 2D region I would like to visualize.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is a 2 dimensional histogram. [Matplotlib.pyplot](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html) makes this really easy.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Make some points
npoints = 500
x = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=3, size=npoints)
y = np.random.uniform(low=-3, high=3, size=npoints)

# Make the plot
plt.hist2d(x, y)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from just the color array by setting `extent` and `aspect` keywords of `imshow`

```
import matplotlib as plt
import numpy as np

zval = np.random.rand(100, 100)
plt.imshow(zvals, extent=[0,3,-3,3], aspect="auto")
plt.show()
```

What you get is the `zval` array just "crunched in" the `[0:3, -3:3]` range. Plot just the `zval` array in `imshow` to convince yourself of this.