# How to visualise 2D grid data

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, visualization

I would like to visualise 2D grid data. So I have a 2D matrix with some columns and rows. Each cell has its own value as a float number. The result I want to get when I plot the grid data should look like this;

[Visualised 2D data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJmyB.png)

There seems to be a solution to this problem in this link: [2D grid data visualization in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229971/2d-grid-data-visualization-in-python)

**However,** it seems to use an outdated library from matplotlib. Could you please help?

Comment: Why do you think it's outdated? This approach is still valid.

Comment: No, the solution you link to is valid. Could you rather show the exact problem you face?

Comment: I get an error saying this: "cannot import name 'mpl' " when I try the code in that link. I did search online and found someone saying it is outdated. Sorry if it was wrong. I don't know why I am getting that error

Comment: Oh, there was a simple mistake in that code. I corrected it.